# Is it necessary to normalize data when using Matlab's ANN?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, normalize

Is it necessary to use [`mapstd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapstd.html) or [`mapminmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html) to normalize the data when training a neural network in Matlab? Both functions documentation state that this is done automatically when declaring `feedforwardnet`, however, I have read that people still normalize it. So why would I normalize it if it's done automatically by Matlab? Is it necessary?

Comment: Can you add a reference to where you read that the data are normalized automatically? I see nothing obvious about it from [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html). Also, there are various different types of normalization, people might pre-normalize their data if they wish to do so differently from the default behavior. People also might not know the tool normalizes for them as there are many tools and many versions, it's hard to comment without seeing actual code and actual examples of people normalizing anyway

Comment: Well I read it here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html it specifically explains the steps of normalization and then they add "For most networks, including feedforwardnet, these steps are done automatically, so that you only need to use the sim command."

Comment: And where did you read that people still normalize it? Also the [`mapstd` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapstd.html) have that identical line (i.e. *For most networks, including feedforwardnet, these steps are done automatically, so that you only need to use the sim command.*) so it raises the question of which one does the network choose automatically!

Comment: Well from what I have read from several sources, people using Matlab still talk about normalization. So I'm wondering if I normalize the data the neural network will be more accurate, or if it would be unnecessary because Matlab does it automatically...

Comment: Yeah but that may depend on what functions and versions they are using, what are you using. The stats toolbox also has neural networks which probably work differently. You should specify in your question which toolbox you are using btw.

Comment: I did not know there was an alternative for Neural networks in Matlab. I'm using feedforwardnet which is part of the Neural Network Toolbox (the other option, newff, seems to be outdated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On initial stages of learning you can omit normalization. But if you will have desire to improve your learning results significantly you'll not be able to avoid normalization. I can even tell you more, you maybe even will need scaling of data as well. As a way of example, our brain do normalization as well. For example if you hear, that some country spend 100 million of dollars for housing. Then your brain give question what is population of that country. If it is small country with population 1000 citizens, you can consider it as big value. But if it is big country with 1.2 billion of citizens you'll consider it as drop of water in ocean. If to summarize, initially you can omit normalization, but at improvement stage it will not be avoidable.

Comment: I see... But isn't the data automatically normalized by Matlab when using feedforwardnet?

Comment: Matlab will normalize your data before usage. But for practical tasks I found that Matlab normalization wasn't enough. Good results was achieved often after normalization and scaling

Comment: I see, this is helpful. Thank you! Btw do you know of any good source for the correct way of normalizing the data (for instance should I normalize it using my own method, or should I call mapstd/mapminmax)?

Comment: It just depends from data. You can try to use mapstd/mapminmax. Then you can try to do the same step but to remove extreme values, then you can also try sigmoidal or softmax normalization ( this normalization doesn't require to remove outliers ). Also you can try to add scaling which will make error surface more round

Comment: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=BrnHR7esWmkC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=softmax+normalization&source=bl&ots=Ux1z_o2GLL&sig=_2eF6zanXybkgVgFEYnu3lgoBD4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAmoVChMIu_G9-eLcxgIVCtssCh1IGwPK#v=onepage&q=softmax%20normalization&f=false this link describes sigmoidal normalization

Comment: If my answer was useful, can you please either up vote it or mark as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `feedforwardnet` it's not necessary, but if you use outdate functions like `newff` you need. For futher [details](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapstd.html).